# Anonymous function with rest parameter throwing NullPointerException

Tags: clojure

Here's the function

```
(#(
   (println (str "first: " %1))
   (println (str "second: " %2))
   (println (str "rest: " (clojure.string/join ", " %&))))
 "f" "s" "x" "y" "z")
```

When running this in cider **I get the desired result** but at the end I see that I am also getting a NullPointerException.

It seems that this form of anonymous function has some issues with destructuring.

Because, when I try the following form of anonymous function, it works.

```
((fn [f s & rest]
    (println (str "first: " f))
    (println (str "second: " s))
    (println (str (clojure.string/join ", " rest))))
   "f" "s" "x" "y" "z")
```

Can someone explain why is this happening ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `do`:

```
(#(do
   (println (str "first: " %1))
   (println (str "second: " %2))
   (println (str "rest: " (clojure.string/join ", " %&))))
 "f" "s" "x" "y" "z")
```

Without the `do`, you're trying to invoke the result of the first `println`, (i.e. `nil`) on the remaining elements of the list. `fn` has an implicit `do`.

For a minimal case, compare `((println))` and `(do (println))`

Comment: Ah... makes sense. Thank you very much.