# 'if' with multiple expressions throwing NullPointerException

Tags: clojure

I am a bit puzzled with the behavior of `if`. The following code works fine:

```
(if true 
  (let [x "whatever"]
    (println "TRUE 1")
    (println "TRUE 2")))
```

returns:

```
TRUE 1
TRUE 2
nil
```

But if the `let` expression is removed:

```
(if true 
  (
    (println "TRUE 1")
    (println "TRUE 2")))
```

it returns a `NullPointerException` as well:

```
TRUE 1
TRUE 2
NullPointerException   user/eval8051 (NO_SOURCE_FILE:4)
```

I suspect it is due to the `println` returning a `nil`. But then why does it work when a `let` is introduced? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33324187/anonymous-function-with-rest-parameter-throwing-nullpointerexception

Comment: It's worth getting clear on some technical points about terminology, or about what happened:  The first expression doesn't *return* `"TRUE 1"` and `"TRUE 2"`; it prints them, and returns `nil`.  Since you are executing this in the REPL, the return value is printed, too: `"nil"` is printed.  You might think, then, that in the second expression, only the `NullPointerException` is returned, but that's not quite right.  The exception isn't the value of the `if` expression; it's an exception.  It interrupted the evaluation of the expression.  Since it wasn't *caught*, it was printed out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key part is this block

```
((println "TRUE 1")
 (println "TRUE 2"))
```

What this does is evaluate the `println`s, turning the expression into this:

```
(nil nil)
```

And then, because of the additional parenthesis, it tries to call `nil` as a function, with `nil` as the argument. Since `nil` is not a function, it throws the exception. The reason it worked in the first case was because it had the `let` to evaluate instead. Since a `let` will evaluate every expression in its body (and doesn't try to treat the results as a function), it behaves correctly.

If you want to evaluate multiple expressions, you should use [`do`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/do)

```
(if true 
    (do (println "TRUE 1")
        (println "TRUE 2")))
```

or, since there's no "else" part, you can just use [`when`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/when)

```
(when true
      (println "TRUE 1")
      (println "TRUE 2"))
```

The important thing to remember is that in Clojure, unlike in C-style languages, you can't just add parenthesis around expressions without changing the meaning. If you wrap something in parenthesis (without quoting it), it's going to try and evaluate it as a function invocation.

Comment: Makes sense now. Thanks for the lovely explanation.